# Embedding JW player

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I used tutorial from here: http://developer.longtailvideo.com/contributors/nyboe/index.html
To embed player to my page. I downloaded all that I needed. But it seems that embedding wasn't working. I tried another approach and it worked.
But still I want to use list items and javascript on my page to seek through video.
I don't get it, same code, same browser and theirs works fine, but mine don't.
Also I'm curious why they can embed this player on few different ways, but I can manage only one to work since it's all the same.
When I try this example I get error in javascript console: **uncaught ReferenceError: swfobject is not defined**
I tried this way:

```
var swfobject = new SWFObject();
swfobject.embedSWF("jwplayer/player.swf", "placeholder1", "300", "196", "9.0.115", false, flashvars, params, attributes);
```

But that I got:
**Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'embedSWF'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run SWF on your local computer. Perhaps different security settings is the reason for the different behavior.

Comment: So how could I test all this is I can't run it on local machine?
For example, javascript to position at some second in video on link click?

Comment: use a personal web server, so you access your page via h**p://localhost/my page.html. use IIS or even apache, like WAMP